# Equivalent of python:scipy.optimize() in C++?

Tags: c++, python, optimization, scipy, quantlib

Specifically I am looking for an optimizer function like scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b .. Can someone help me please ? Or provide pointers ?

Thanks!

Comment: Quick search produces [dlib](http://dlib.net/optimization.html).

Comment: http://www.chokkan.org/software/liblbfgs/

Answer (score 10):

The [dlib](http://dlib.net/optimization.html) C++ library has a number of optimizers in it including L-BFGS.  It's free and the optimization tools are header-only so there is nothing to install or configure.  There is also a relevant [example program](http://dlib.net/optimization_ex.cpp.html) that shows you how to use the L-BFGS optimizer.

Answer (score 1):

If still someone looking for, use [LBFGS++](https://lbfgspp.statr.me/) they also introduce the recently Box-constrained version. I have been using this for a while. You can find some good examples on their official website.